# Consume SOAP web service in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, wsdl

We are trying to consume a SOAP Web service in RoR. using SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory with the following code:

```
  wsdl = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new("http://<domain>/WSDL/v4.0/iLON100.WSDL")
  proxy = wsdl.create_rpc_driver
  proxy.get({:iLonItem => [{:Item => {:UCPTname => "Net/LON/Motion406"}}]})
```

The parameter on the get service is represented through the following XML:

```
<Get xmlns="http://wsdl.echelon.com/web_services_ns/ilon100/v4.0/message/">
  <iLonItem>
    <Item xsi:type="LON_Network_Cfg">
      <UCPTname>MyNetwork</UCPTname>
    </Item>
  </iLonItem>
</Get>
```

But I keep getting this error: **nil not allowed: UCPTname**

Comment: You can turn on a wiredump by setting `proxy.wiredump_dev = $stdout`.  Then, compare the SOAP request to what you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks. I think my problem lies on converting those xml structure to ruby hash and/or array so I could pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it, thanks to `proxy.wiredump_dev = $stdout`, I was able to sniff around the SOAP response/request.

The hash equivalent on the xml above is

```
{:iLonItem => 
  {:Item => [{:UCPTname => 'Net/LON/Motion406'}]}
}
```

I am such a noob in Ruby!

Comment: - same here - Welcome to the ruby noob club :)

Answer (score 0):

Not used SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory - but I have used [Savon](http://savon.rubiii.com/).

Do you have another/working way to call the method, eg [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) ?

I then use something like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to compare the message sent via Savon and soapUI to see what the difference is...

HTH, Chris

Comment: Solved it. Thanks to `proxy.wiredump_dev = $stdout`, I was able to sniff around the SOAP response.